# In Ajax how to remove search results when user empty the search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm learning Ajax and using following practice code to display the search results. But I noticed once the user backspace and empty the search result box, the results still remain there. It will be ideal if results are removed completely when user empty the search box. So when user start typing, results start populating and when he empty the box, there is nothing to display. My code is:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val(),
        myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        var output = '<ul class = "searchresults">';
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if ((val.name.search(myExp) !== -1) ||
                    (val.bio.search(myExp) !== -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<h2>' + val.name + '</h2>';
                output += '<img src="images/' + val.shortname + '_tn.jpg" alt = "' + val.name + '"/>';
                output += '<p>' + val.bio + '</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you can conditionally check the length of `searchField`, and when it is 0 you do not make any AJAX call at all, and simply empty the `#update` element, i.e. `$('#update').empty()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if it's empty after each key up, and if it is you should abort the ajax request and empty the result list.
to check you can add this code after the searchField declaration:

```
if(searchField==""){
    $('#update').html("");   //to empty the result list
    return;                  //return is to abort the operation
}
```

Good luck